# KDB Query to update a column with list

Tags: kdb

I need to update a column with a list which has just one symbol. Below one is not working. Note that city is a column which takes list of symbols.

```
update city: enlist `Lodnon from `user where id in (1,2,3);
```

Answer (score 4):

You current query is very close. You want to provide an atom (i.e. `` `london `` ) rather than a list:

`` update city:`london from user where id in 1 2 3 ``

The query you suggested will fail with a length error (you're providing a list with 1 element to replace 3 column entries, assuming there are 3 records with id in 1 2 3).

Edit: To have the actual column values enlisted, you will have to make sure that the `city` column takes lists (i.e. applying the keyword `meta` to your table should return a capital S in the `t` column for `city`.

Assuming your `city` column currently has a small `s` when running `meta user`, you can update this by running:

`` update city:enlist each city from `user ``

Then, the following will make the change you desired:

`` update city:city:\:enlist`london from user where id in 1 2 3 ``

Comment: This works, but `london value is not going in a list. I should see enlist london in database.

Comment: Ah, I see -- edited the above for having the city column values as lists ^

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to remain as a list you could do something like

```
{update city:(x)#enlist `london from `user where id in 1 2 3}count select from t where id in 1 2 3
```

Or to tidy this up, you could use

```
update city:count[i]#enlist `London from t where id in 1 2 3
```

As is the `i` in the count will be the same length as the list due to filtering in the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use the `?[boolean_list;if_true;if_false]` operator as follows:

```
/ this is just to create a test table
t:([] id:(1;2;3;4); city:4#`)

/ check if each element of t`id is in (1;2;3)
/ 1) `London if true, ` if false
/ 2) assign t[`city]
t[`city]:?[in[t`id;(1;2;3)];`London;`]
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to do it with the following.

```
update city: 3#enlist enlist `Lodnon from `user where id in (1,2,3);
```

Comment: Your answer can be improved by adding more information on what your code does and how it helps the OP.